# WCF RESTful - HTTPS for a single operation method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

It is possible to enable https for a single operation method in a RESTful WCF?
I'm using this service for a mobile application so i don't want enable the https for the whole service.

Sorry about my english...

Comment: What is the reason you would not want the whole thing secure?

Comment: Mobile performance, some of the other methods return a big amount of data.

Comment: What's the performance difference between running your biggest operation over SSL and clear text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for a single endpoint. The binding of the endpoint needs to decide whether to use HTTP or HTTPS (based on its transport binding element). If you really want to do that (and you may not need to - try profiling the "big" responses with and without SSL and you may find that the difference is not that much) you can define two endpoints, one with SSL for that single operation, and one without SSL for the other operations, as in the example below:

```
public class StackOverflow_22865228
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISecureOperation
    {
        [WebGet]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IInsecureOperations
    {
        [WebGet]
        int Subtract(int x, int y);
        [WebGet]
        int Multiply(int x, int y);
    }
    public class Service : ISecureOperation, IInsecureOperations
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
        public int Subtract(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
        public int Multiply(int x, int y) { return x * y; }
    }
    public static void StartService()
    {
        string baseAddressHttp = "http://localhost:8000/Service";
        string baseAddressHttps = "https://localhost:8888/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddressHttp), new Uri(baseAddressHttps));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISecureOperation), new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport), "")
            .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IInsecureOperations), new WebHttpBinding(), "")
            .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, but, i'm also keeping the user session, i will not be able to keep this session with different endpoints, correct?
         [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]


    private readonly HttpContext context;
MySessionClass sessionObj 
        { 
            get {                
                return context.Session["SESSAO"] as MySessionClass;
            }
}

Comment: No, you won't keep the session. You should definitely check whether HTTPS will really be a problem for all operations, there's a big chance it won't...